# HTML form target redirects to external wbsite

Tags: html, forms, target

Just curious as to whether or not the  can target an external website?

```
<html>
<body>
<form target="http://www.google.com">
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Seems to just open up a new window with the same page when i click submit. Any ideas? I want it to go directly to google!

Comment: I think you want `action`, that one can hold an URL. `target` tells the browser in which window to open the url

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the `target` attribute and confusing it with the `action` attribute.

The `target` attribute for forms is used to reference frames and iframes, that is, to which open window to post the form to.

If you want to post data to google, use the `action` attribute of the form, which tells the form where to post/get data:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://www.google.com">
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```